# Is it possible to observe live data in view models, without using switch map (which creates a new live data)?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-viewmodel

Is it possible to observe live data in a view model without creating a new live data? As I understand, one should never .observe in view models as this results in issues with the life cycle. Thus, one usually uses Transformations.switchMap(), but this creates a new live data which I have to assign. Ideally, I would like to do something like this:

```
val liveData: LiveData<String>
liveData.switchMap {
    // Do stuff
}
```

or

```
liveData.observe {
    // Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [observeForever](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LiveData.html#observeforever) but in that case, you have to take care of disposing it when viewmode clear

Comment: Thanks, I've heard of this is as well, but it doesn't really seem optimal either.

Comment: @Zlash then according to my knowledge you can only do it by declaring another LiveData or Rx Observable

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly. The reason why you should not observe something in viewModel is because it's not bound to the correct lifecycle. Best way to do things is to observe your LiveData in view and intercept your data in the ViewModel using a MediatorLiveData and post the processed data directly in the LiveData variable.